# why primary expression don't include template_id

Tags: c++, bnf

I have such code, compile with "g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 test.cpp ",which doesn't compile because error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vec;
  for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
      vec.push_back(i);
    }
  std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),std::less<int>);  //should be std::less<int>()
}
```

But the standard says:

```
primary-expression:
  literal
  this
  ( expression )
  id-expression
  lambda-expression

id-expression:
  unqualified-id
  qualified-id

unqualified-id:
  identifier
  operator-function-id
  conversion-function-id
  literal-operator-id
  ~ class-name
  ~ decltype-specifier
 template-id

template-id
  simple-template-id

simple-template-id
  template-name <template-argument-list>
```

So it seems std::less is a template-id, so it's a primary-expression.

Comment: which compiler you are using?

Comment: FWIW, Clang: *error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction*

Comment: @MantoshKumar, Probably GCC. 4.9 gives the error.

Comment: Well it looks like there is problem in Clang compilation error message. I ran the same program in VS2010 and got the following "error C2275: 'std::less<_Ty>' : illegal use of this type as an expression".

Comment: @MantoshKumar, There's nothing wrong with the Clang error. It's basically saying "you have half of an expression of this type, but you're missing the other half".

Comment: Technically, `std::less<int>` is a *qualified-id*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being grammatically correct doesn't necessarily make the program *semantically* correct. The grammar production from primary-expression -> template-id is there to allow use of a specialization of a function template as an expression, e.g, this is valid:

```
template <typename T>
bool less(const T& a, const T& b) { return a < b; }

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), less<int>);
}
```

A template-id that refers to a class template, however, is not usable as an expression.

Comment: +1. The difference between semantics and syntax is subtle at the best of times and even more so in C++. The standard does not distinguish between different flavours of ill-formed programs: it simply defines a well-formed program as a "C++ program constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the One Definition Rule", and an ill-formed program as one which is not well-formed.

Comment: @Casey. I agree almost of you. I think the program is semantically wrong, but it do be a primary expression, so does that mean g++ report a wrong type of error? It seems clang's error code " illegal use of this type as an expression" more reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

This is the difference between the parser and the semantic analyzer. C++'s grammar tells you only what is grammatical -- what will pass through the parser. For example, the grammar would also allow you to do something like:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ~MyClass);
```

for the same reason -- because `~ class-name` is an `unqualified-id`. You need to look at the semantic rules of the language to determine if a program is well formed, not just look at the grammar, and the semantic rules of the language require a value here, rather than a type.

---

Specifically, I believe the standard says this via the rules for the function call operator (`()`) at C++11 5.2.2 [expr.call]/4: (emphasis mine)

> When a function is called, **each parameter** (8.3.5) **shall be initialized** (**8.5**, 12.8, 12.1) with its corresponding argument.

8.5 [dcl.init]/1: (emphasis mine)

> A declarator can specify an initial value for the identifier being declared. **The identifier designates a variable being initialized**.

But I'm no standards scholar and I'm not on the committee, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I haven't thought about this in terms of expressions. But the way I think about it - `std::sort` wants an object for it's third parameter. `std::less<int>` is just a type declaration. `std::less<int>()` creates the object that `std::sort` requires.